# React render vs. UseState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm pretty new to this and can't really figure out how the render works - stuck with UseState for now :) -. Since I see a lot of people using it I wanted to ask for advice on what I'm doing wrong.
Here are 2 examples one with UseState that works great and other with render that does nothing, I added some style so it looks kind of acceptable for anyone trying it out.

Any help appreciated, thank you

// USESTATE

```
    const [newColor, setNewColor] = useState('green');
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setBorder()
      }, [newColor])
    
      function setBorder() {
        if (newColor === 'green') {
          document.getElementById('green').style.borderColor = "orange";
          document.getElementById('yellow').style.borderColor = "black";
          document.getElementById('red').style.borderColor = "black";
      }
      if (newColor === 'yellow') {
          document.getElementById('yellow').style.borderColor = "orange";
          document.getElementById('green').style.borderColor = "black";
          document.getElementById('red').style.borderColor = "black";
      }
      if (newColor === 'red') {
          document.getElementById('red').style.borderColor = "orange";
          document.getElementById('green').style.borderColor = "black";
          document.getElementById('yellow').style.borderColor = "black";
      }
      }
    
      const changeBg = () => {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
        <div style={{width: '240px', height: '88px', border: '3px solid black', 'borderRadius': '10px'}}>
        <div id="green" onClick={(e) => setNewColor(e.target.id)}    style={{width: '40px', height: '40px', background: 'green', border: '3px solid black', float: 'left', margin: '20px 0 0 30px', 'borderRadius': '10px', cursor: 'pointer'}}></div>
        <div id="yellow" onClick={(e) => setNewColor(e.target.id)}   style={{width: '40px', height: '40px', background: 'yellow', border: '3px solid black', float: 'left', margin: '20px 0 0 20px', 'borderRadius': '10px', cursor: 'pointer'}}></div>
        <div id="red" onClick={(e) => setNewColor(e.target.id)}      style={{width: '40px', height: '40px', background: 'red', border: '3px solid black', float: 'left', margin: '20px 0 0 20px', 'borderRadius': '10px', cursor: 'pointer'}}></div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={changeBg}>SAVE</button>
        </div>
      );
```

// RENDER

```
    class Test1 extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                newColor: 'green'
            }
        }
    
        componentDidUpdate() {
            if (this.newColor === 'green') {
                document.getElementById('green').style.borderColor = "orange";
                document.getElementById('yellow').style.borderColor = "black";
                document.getElementById('red').style.borderColor = "black";
            }
            if (this.newColor === 'yellow') {
                document.getElementById('yellow').style.borderColor = "orange";
                document.getElementById('green').style.borderColor = "black";
                document.getElementById('red').style.borderColor = "black";
            }
            if (this.newColor === 'red') {
                document.getElementById('red').style.borderColor = "orange";
                document.getElementById('green').style.borderColor = "black";
                document.getElementById('yellow').style.borderColor = "black";
            }
        }
    
        render() {
    
            const changeBg = () => {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.newColor;
              }
    
    
            return (
                <div>
                <div style={{width: '240px', height: '88px', border: '3px solid black', 'borderRadius': '10px'}}>
                <div id="green" onClick={(e) => this.state={newColor: e.target.id}}    style={{width: '40px', height: '40px', background: 'green', border: '3px solid black', float: 'left', margin: '20px 0 0 30px', 'borderRadius': '10px', cursor: 'pointer'}}></div>
                <div id="yellow" onClick={(e) => this.state={newColor: e.target.id}}   style={{width: '40px', height: '40px', background: 'yellow', border: '3px solid black', float: 'left', margin: '20px 0 0 20px', 'borderRadius': '10px', cursor: 'pointer'}}></div>
                <div id="red" onClick={(e) => this.state={newColor: e.target.id}}      style={{width: '40px', height: '40px', background: 'red', border: '3px solid black', float: 'left', margin: '20px 0 0 20px', 'borderRadius': '10px', cursor: 'pointer'}}></div>
                </div>
                <button onClick={changeBg}>SAVE</button>
                </div>
              );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should never<sup>*</sup> update DOM directly in react as you do.
In both of the examples you are doing that.
The reason why second example doesn't work, `componentDidUpdate` is called when update happens (e.g. state change or props change), that doesn't happen because you aren't calling `setState` in second example; rather directly assigning to `this.state`. Also it should be `this.state.newColor` as noted in comments.

Idiomatic way to solve this in react is this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [newColor, setNewColor] = React.useState('green');

  const changeBg = () => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          width: '240px',
          height: '88px',
          border: '3px solid black',
          borderRadius: '10px',
        }}
      >
        {['green', 'yellow', 'red'].map((x) => (
          <div
            onClick={(e) => setNewColor(x)}
            style={{
              width: '40px',
              height: '40px',
              background: x,
              border: '3px solid black',
              borderColor: newColor === x ? 'orange' : 'black',
              float: 'left',
              margin: '20px 0 0 30px',
              borderRadius: '10px',
              cursor: 'pointer',
            }}
          ></div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={changeBg}>SAVE</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Although the boxes aren't well centered now, because you had different margin for first element, when all `div`s were written out by hand. But now I have same margin for all of them because I used a loop. I will leave it up to you to adjust it.

---

<sup>*</sup> Well in [rare](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) cases you can, when say integrating with 3rd party libraries, but in that case you should make sure react doesn't touch that part of the DOM.

Comment: In the second example, it should also be `this.state.newColor`

Comment: @Arkellys yep..

Comment: And `this.state={newColor: e.target.id}}` is wrong too, `setState()` should be called to update the state.

Comment: @Arkellys Hmm yeah, I didn't notice that, hm guess need to rewrite the answer